# Can't enable Apple Two Step Authentication

Tags: security, apple-id, authentication

I see from all of the various blogs and news sites that Apple finally has two step authentication with their Apple ID. That's great -- especially with the latest security hole where you can now reset someone's Apple ID password with just the ID and the user's birthday.

However, I don't seem to be able to turn on two step authentication:

Here's what I do:

1. Go to https://appleid.apple.com/
2. Click on the *Manage Your Apple ID* button.
3. Sign in.
4. Click on *Password and Security*.
5. I'm now asked my *security questions*.
6. I answer my security questions.
7. And, now I can change my password, security questions, my *rescue email*, and my birthdate.

Why can't I turn on Two-step authentication? Am I not going to the correct place? I'm trying to follow the directions on Apple's website, but I don't get the two-step verification option.

---

## Response:

> When I first went to the Password and Security page. I answered the questions. And then got the normal setting page for Password and Security. But I could not see an option for the two-step. What I missed was its above all the settings. You may be doing the same. Thats an actual screen shot of the top of the Password and Security page and show the "Get started"

Nope. I don't see that...

[image: Apple ID Password and Security Page]

I'm going to see if I can contact Apple tomorrow on this. Maybe take my Macbook to the Apple Store tomorrow.

Comment: [From Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5570?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) "Initially, two-step verification is being offered in the U.S., UK, Australia, Ireland, and New Zealand" - are you in one of those countries?

Comment: To make sure, I checked my Apple ID address. It's in the United States.

Comment: Had the same problem than the one you're facing ! Until David point out this is only available to some countries ... They are really stupid to make that kind of features not globally available !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was a slooooowww rollout. I checked a few weeks later, and found the two step authentication offered, and filled it out.

Answer (score 2):

I missed it the first time. It should be at the top.
of the the Security page.

---

[image]

---

Comment: When I first went to the Password and Security page. I answered the questions. And then got the normal setting page for Password and Security. But I could not see an option for the two-step. What I missed was its above all the settings. You may be doing the same. Thats an actual screen shot of the top of the Password and Security page and show the "Get started"

Comment: See my **RESPONSE** in my answer. Unfortunately, I don't see that.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your password is a complex one and has been changed recently, the most logical problem is that your password isn't new enough for the system to offer you the two-step authorization change.

It is a bit of a pain to change the password (since you will need to change it everywhere - perhaps multiple times on each Computer and iOS device), but once you've made a new password, you should be able to quit your browser and then log in anew and see the request two-step authorization wording and controls.

Do note, that you may have to wait at least 3 days from the time you changed your password to request two-step, and once you request it, you may have a second 3 day wait period to ensure that all the emails Apple sends have a chance to be delivered.

This is to protect you from someone else enabling two-step authentication and allow you to contact Apple and stop your account from being hijacked.

Also, I wouldn't go to an Apple retail store for support with Apple ID. They can't log in to your account or do anything but help you fill out the web form for support. Yes, they may have someone who knows how it's supposed to to work, but your details show you understand how it should work and you might just need to [open a support ticket with Apple ID support](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/) if you can't enable things yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Either your address is blank or you are from country where this feature hasn't been rolled out yet. I changed country to USA and i showed up right away.

Comment: A little late to the party? I answered this back in April 30th. I tried to do the two step authorization as soon as I heard about it. It didn't get rolled out to my account until 6 weeks later. I was able to do the two step authentication. I just had to be patient. Thanks for answering. Maybe it'll help someone else.

Comment: :) I tried to do this today and may be due to my short attention span I couldn't find a solution so to help people like me I posted the answer here.

Answer (score -2):

I was so upset when I got my phone Ana found that I had to wait for 2 days for the two step authorization.  Here is what I did.  I created a new Apple ID using a different email address I already had (you can't use an apple url address), I used a gmail account.  Then I set it up and created a password thru apple. Just go into your iCloud from the menu, scroll to the bottom and sign out.  Then replace it with the new temporary account until your 3 days pass and you can log back in to your original Apple ID.  It worked!  I can use the watch now!!!

Comment: This is a Bad Idea™. Anything acquired from the App Store or iTunes Store during the time you are signed in with your "temporary" account will be registered to that account, meaning you will have to juggle two accounts for the rest of the time you are using any of that content. This will cause you to have sign in and out of accounts as you try to update apps, watch or listen to content, etc. Similarly, any data synced during this period (contacts, notes and so forth) will be synced to the wrong account.